# Python : how to print values of all constants from an import?

Tags: python, variables, import, names

I group and store my constants (can be a dict.) in a separate python file. E.g. parameters.py :

```
HARD_COPY=True
BOOKS={
    2018:{"author":"Hugo"}
    }
etc.
```

In a source file, I write :

```
import parameters as para
```

Of course, I can use the variables knowing their names (para.BOOKS, etc.).
But I wish to display their names and values, whatever those names can be.

If I write dir(para), I can see the list of these names.
But how can I print their values ?

I'd like to display :

```
My defined variables in parameters.py : 
HARD_COPY : True
BOOKS     : {2018:{"author":"Hugo"}}
etc.
```

Comment: See [**`vars`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars), and [**`pprint`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint), e.g.:`pprint(vars(parameters))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getattr` to access its value by name.

```
import parameters as para


print('My defined variables in parameters.py : ')

for variable in dir(para):
    if not variable.startswith('__'):
        print(variable, ':', getattr(para, variable))
```

Output:

```
My defined variables in parameters.py :
BOOKS : {2018: {'author': 'Hugo'}}
HARD_COPY : True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at storing constants (or config variables) you should consider them storing them in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) format.

Let's say you had a config file called `config.json` which had the following values

```
{
  "HARD_COPY": true,
  "BOOKS": {
    "2018": {
      "author": "Hugo"
    }
  }
}
```

You could load these values from a `.py` file using the following

```
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

To then iterate over these values you could do the following

**Python 2.7**

```
for key, val in my_books.iteritems(): 
    print(key, val)

>>>('HARD_COPY', True)
>>>('BOOKS', {2018: {'author': 'Hugo'}})
```

**Python 3**

```
for key, val in my_books.items():
    print(key, val)

>>> HARD_COPY True
>>> BOOKS {2018: {'author': 'Hugo'}}
```

Comment: Updated to include a Python3 option

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import parameters as para
for name in dir(para):
    if not name.startswith('__'):
        myvalue = eval('para.%s'%name)
        print(name,"is",myvalue)
```

Output:

```
BOOKS is {2018: {'author': 'Hugo'}}
HARD_COPY is True
```

Comment: There's no need to use `eval` here.  Not only is `eval` slow, `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a "normal" module, you can use `__dict__`:

```
import parameters as para

for k, v in para.__dict__.items():
    if k.isupper():
        print("name:", k, "value:", v)
```

I have used `isupper()` since that is the convention for constants (although they are not really).

Gives:

```
name: HARD_COPY value: True
name: BOOKS value: {2018: {'author': 'Hugo'}}
```

EDIT with thanks to @Aran-Fey

Comment: Also [**`vars`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)